# How to Center Align vertically a TextField Content in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a **TextField** but it's value can't be seen completely and almost Half of it's content goes below the Field.

what should I add to this TextField?

Here is the code:

```
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                        TextField(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(60.dp)
                                .width(230.dp)
                                .padding(0.dp),
                            value = text.value,
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 25.sp,
                            ),
                            onValueChange = { nextText ->
                                text.value = nextText
                            },
                            label = {
                                Text(
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                                    text = "search",
                                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                                    fontSize = 13.sp
                                )
                            },
                            singleLine = true,
                            trailingIcon = {
                                IconButton(onClick = {

                                }) {
                                    Icon(
                                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                                        contentDescription = "Search Button",
                                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp)
                                    )
                                }
                            }, keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Search
                            ),
                            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {

                            })
                        )
```

And it's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You have to increase the height. Use height(70.dp)

Comment: yeah. looks like I have to. thanks